# How to call native code from IntelliJ Plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-native-interface, intellij-plugin

How example, I have a bunch of native libraries for several architectures:

> mylib.dylib, mylib.so, mylib.dll

There are JNI bindings in the libs, which I want to call from the plugin itself, like this:

```
external fun hello(): Void

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("hello")
        }
    }
```

I want to distribute these libs among with **.jar**.
I've tried to add binaries inside src folder and link them via **Project Structure - Modules** and **Project Structure - Libraries** with no result.
Due to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81939), I can conclude that such a case should be possible.
Should I add something inside **build.gradle.kts**? Or can I use c-interop somehow?

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development so that IDEA Core team could have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd connected with Idea developer and he said that native libs should be placed inside following folder.

> myplugin/main/resources/lib

That's way libs will be copied to .jar.
To unpack lib from the .jar I'm using [this library](https://github.com/scijava/native-lib-loader).
You must rewrite it in Kotlin and place classes inside plugin codebase. Also remove Logger library, as it will break Sandbox. Be aware of abstract properties in DefaultJNIExtractor, as Java-to-Kotlin converter fails on this piece.